# Java mail, IMAP, out of memory when using fetchprofileitem.message during getcontent

Tags: java, email, out-of-memory, jakarta-mail

I am fetching mails with content and attachments from huge mailboxes (a folder contains 1.000.000 mails and with attachments) using javamail api and IMAP protocol. My problem is, when I use the ***`FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE`*** for performance, I get memory problems when performing the part.getContent().

Suppose we have 2000 mails and their UIDs are numbered 1-2000. (I know they can be different). First we get all message templates.

```
Message allMessages[] = folder.getMessagesByUID(0, 2000);
```

Then we fetch the messages by using a fetch profile, but we only fetch the first block 0-1000 messages to prevent huge memory consumption.

```
ArrayList<message> firstGroup = new ArrayList<message>();
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
   firstGroup.add(allMessages[i]);

// convert it to message array
Message firstGroupMessages [] = firstGroup.toArray(new Message[0]);
```

Now we use fetch profile to fetch all message data of the first group (0-1000)

```
FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(FetchProfileItem.Message);
// other items such as Envelope, flags, content info, x-mailer etc.

folder.fetch(firstGroupMessages , fp);

// and we process the messages
for (Message m : firstGroupMessages ) {
    processHeader(m);
    processBody(m);
    ((IMAPMessage)m).invalidateHeaders(); // i do not need this message anymore
}

void processBody(Part p) {
   ...
   // any call to p.getContent causes huge memory consumption
   Object o = p.getContent();
   if (o instanceof InputStream) {
     ...
```

When I run this part for the range 0-1000, a memory block is allocted. If the processing of the first block is completed, and clear the arraylist first group, generate a new arraylist and pick up messages with UID 1000-2000 from the message array allMessages.

```
    ArrayList<message> secondGroup = new ArrayList<message>();
    for (i = 1000; i < 2000; i++) 
       secondGroup .add(allMessages[i]);
       // convert it to message array
       Message secondGroupMessages [] = secondGroup .toArray(new Message[0]);
```

And then call the fetchprofile again and process the messages. But after finishing the first block, the memory resources are not released and performing the second group uses extra memory and it goes until out of memory cases.

When I remove the `part.getContent()` calls during the body process, no memory problems occur. Additionally, if I remove the `FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE` from fetch profile, the memory problems are over.

I know, that the fetch profile MESSAGE performs prefetch off all data and increases performance on getContent calls and improves the performance but why memory usage increases always even if processing of a single message has completed?

Comment: Seriously? **a folder contains 1.000.000 mails and with attachments**

Comment: Yes. We have to fetch all of them.

Comment: @benchpresser Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: @Spec closing and reopening the folder solved the memory problem. but closing opening is also a performance cost but the memory problems are over